# Error protocol and QXcbConnection when I run a game after update to Debian Testing Buster

Tags: bash, debian, sh, updates, debian-stretch

I was playing my game normally before the update, I was at Debian 9.3 Stretch.
After update I try to run the game with the same command.

```
bash start-tibia.sh
```

And Output this:

```
    No protocol specified
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Aborted
```

I don't know why this happening.

My system: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6J7b.png)

**Important if I run the application with a normal user it works, but with the root user isn't work.**

Any helps would be appreciated. :B
-Melt